# Is it possible to remove a class from Seaborn Pairplot except in diagnonal?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I have a dataset with three classes of error [-1, 0, 1]. I am interessed in analysing [0] distributions but as it outnumber the other classes it makes scatter plots pretty illegible.

`sns.pairplot(X_test, hue="ERRORS",kind='scatter', markers=["o",".","D"])`
[image]

Is there a way to remove class [0] from the scatter plots but to keep it in the displots?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `PairGrid` instead of `pairplot` and passing a custom plotting function that rejects a number of potential hue-levels:

```
def filtered_scatterplot(x,y,ignore=None,label=None,**kwargs):
    if label is None or ignore is None or label not in np.asarray(ignore):
        sns.scatterplot(x=x,y=y,**kwargs)
        
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
g = sns.PairGrid(penguins, hue="species")
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.map_offdiag(filtered_scatterplot, ignore=['Chinstrap','Gentoo'])
```

[image]